# How do I signal a sqlstate of 00000 (success) from a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want my migration procedures to return standard sqlstate codes when appropriate.  The standard code for a success is "00000" but when I signal this sqlstate I get the following error:

`Error Code: 1407. Bad SQLSTATE: '00000'`

Here's the code that it's complaining about.  It works if I change the status to 01000, so it's not my syntax.

`signal sqlstate '00000'
        set message_text = '::SUCCESS::'`

Comment: See the documentation first https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html : "SIGNAL is the way to *“return” an error*. .. "Class = '00' (success) Illegal. *SQLSTATE values that begin with '00' indicate success and are not valid for SIGNAL.*"

Comment: So: "don't signal" if there is no error. (This also applies to MySQL 8; I should have linked to a more recent documentation from the get-go.)

Answer (score 3):

Per the documentation:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html
>
> In the following descriptions, “unhandled” means that no handler for
>   the signaled SQLSTATE value has been defined with DECLARE ... HANDLER.
>
> ```
> Class = '00' (success)
>
> Illegal. SQLSTATE values that begin with '00' indicate success and are not valid for SIGNAL.
> ```

In other words, you can only use "signal" to return an *ERROR* condition.  *NOT* calling signal implies "success".

```
signal sqlstate '12345'
    set message_text = '::SOME CUSTOM ERROR::'
```

Comment: I originally read the documentation to imply the OP had a bad format.  You're correct - re-reading it (we both cited the same link), "signal" is meant *ONLY* for errors.  Thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: This should be the Accepted Answer. Come on OP, please give this man his points.